# Search regex for Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking to create a regex for searching Notepad++

I have a notepad page with thousands of random codes such as:

```
415615610230
151156125611
161651651516
511111115165
```

I need to search the entire notepad for multiple codes with once search

I know the regex would look like `(415615610230|151156125611|161651651516)`

but what I need to do is build a regex like above by pasting in all my search criteria.

If I have say 100,000 numbers I might need to search the 100,000 numbers for 20 codes/numbers.

lets just say I want to search for

```
5155584865
5155584866
5155584867
5155584868
5155584869
5155584870
5155584871
5155584872
5155584873
5155584874
5155584875
5155584876
5155584877
5155584878
5155584879
5155584880
5155584881
5155584882
5155584883
5155584884
```

The regex should look like:

```
(5155584865|5155584866|5155584867|5155584868|5155584869|5155584870|5155584871|5155584872|5155584873|5155584874|5155584875|5155584876|5155584877|5155584878|5155584879|5155584880|5155584881|5155584882|5155584883|5155584884)
```

Is there a way to build the regex above by just pasting in

```
5155584865
5155584866
5155584867
5155584868
5155584869
5155584870
5155584871
5155584872
5155584873
5155584874
5155584875
5155584876
5155584877
5155584878
5155584879
5155584880
5155584881
5155584882
5155584883
5155584884
```

Or can anyone recommend an easier way to search the entire notepad document?

Comment: Paste the search content in a new notepad file. Make them one line by removing line breaks. Replace all empty spaces with `|` symbol. Add open and close bracket. Your regex ready. Copy and search for it. That is already easy, isn't it?

Comment: Ok so when I have the content and I paste it into a new notepad++ document it appears like this: s7.postimg.org/f9ayo7vd7/… How can I get this to appear like:

(5155584865|5155584866|5155584867|5155584868|5155584869|5155‌​584870|5155584871|51‌​55584872|5155584873|‌​5155584874|515558487‌​5|5155584876|5155584‌​877|5155584878|51555‌​84879|5155584880|515‌​5584881|5155584882|5‌​155584883|5155584884‌​)

Answer (score 0):

copy your space separated numbers in a new document in your notepad++ and then replace all spaces or whitespaces (\s) with the pipe symbol (| or \| if your search mode is regex).

And you do not need the round brackets for your search string

EDIT:
Instructions for converting a list of numbers (line separated) into a regex

1. mark everything (ctrl + a)
2. join rows (ctrl + j)
3. replace (ctrl + h) with

   - search pattern: \s+
   - replace pattern: \|
   - search mode: Regex

Comment: Ok so when I have the content and I paste it into a new notepad++ document it appears like this: https://s7.postimg.org/f9ayo7vd7/2017_02_16_14_13_53_new_1_Notepad_Administ.png

How can I get this to appear like:

(5155584865|5155584866|5155584867|5155584868|5155584869|5155584870|5155584871|5155584872|5155584873|5155584874|5155584875|5155584876|5155584877|5155584878|5155584879|5155584880|5155584881|5155584882|5155584883|5155584884)

Comment: @AdrianStewart: I added a step to step instruction to my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to search for the template above (e.g. starting with 51555848) the you can do

```
/51555848.([^\s]+)/g
```

This will match everything starting with 51555848 and ending with a whitespace.